# How to get the result of a select query in an xml file

Tags: sql, xml

I have an `installations.xml` file which calls for a `database.xml` file.
In my `database.xml` file I want to do a `SELECT` query on a table and see if it returns a row or an error, at the end of executing a script according to the result of this query.
Here is the snippet of my `database.xml`:

```
<target name="ChargerTableArticle" depends="chargerVersionCoribudg">
        <sql classpath="${coribudg.oracle.driver}" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="${coribudg.db.url}" userid="${coribudg.db.user}" password="${coribudg.db.password}" output="../properties/coribudg-version.properties" print="yes" showheaders="false" showtrailers="false" onerror="continue">
          <![CDATA[SELECT "IsNonBudgetaire" FROM "NewArticle";]]>
        </sql>
</target>
```

I don't know what to put in the tag `<sql>`. I just want to retrieve the result of the query `SELECT "IsNonBudgetaire" FROM "NewArticle";` and depending on the result if in case of error I launch another procedure.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your DB vendor and  DB version.

Comment: installations.xml and database.xml -> what application are you using? This could mean anything...